# PyGTK tutorial error?

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm working with Python 2.7 and PyGTK 2.24. I am working with the following tutorial. Please read it for code context.

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PackingDemonstrationProgram.html

The bottom block of code (reprinted below) is throwing the following error when I type it in (verbatum):

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
       sys.stderr.write("usage: packbox.py num, where num is 1, 2, or 3.\n")
       sys.exit(1)
    PackBox1(string.atoi(sys.argv[1]))
    main()
```

> usage: packbox.py num, where num is 1, 2, or 3.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/GTKTutorial/packbox.py",
>   line 161, in 
>       sys.exit(1) SystemExit: 1

Additionally, if I change the code to the following to overcome the first error, I get the next error message:

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 1:
       sys.stderr.write("usage: packbox.py num, where num is 1, 2, or 3.\n")
       sys.exit(1)
    PackBox1(string.atoi(sys.argv[1]))
    main()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/GTKTutorial/packbox.py",
>   line 162, in 
>       PackBox1(string.atoi(sys.argv[1])) IndexError: list index out of
>   range

What is wrong? How do I fix the code so I can work with the tutorial>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it from the command line with `packbox.py 1`, `packbox.py 2`, or `packbox.py 3`.

This will result in there being two arguments (the name of the program and the first thing you pass to it), so you won't trigger the `sys.exit(1)`, and `argv[1]` will be a valid index access.

Answer (score 0):

To run PackBox.py directly from IDLE,

REPLACE:

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.stderr.write("usage: packbox.py num, where num is 1, 2, or 3.\n")
        sys.exit(1)
    PackBox1(string.atoi(sys.argv[1]))
    main()
```

WITH:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    packbox = PackBox1(3)
    main()
```

To see all three example widget arrangements, substitute argument (3) with arguments (1) & (2). Click on X to exit the window; the Quit buttons aren't connected in this code.